# What on earth is a [tick]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Shall we put a [tick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tick) in the box for burninating the tag (less than 150 posts tagged)? Honestly, what sort of "tick" are we talking about (since the tag description and excerpt are both empty)? A `CheckBox` tick? The measurement of time (100 ns = 1 tick, I believe)? Besides, who can be an expert of ticks?

<sup>And here come the tick puns... *(runs away)*</sup>

---

<sup>Re/untagging posts tagged with [tick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tick) & [ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ticks) was finally completed at 16:00 18/06/14 (took approximately 1 hour).</sup>

Comment: It's obviously the blood-sucking creatures that annoy me every spring. I don't see how it could be made any more clear.

Comment: There are a lot of questions about "tick" events in timer classes, mostly in the .NET ecosystem.  It might be worth retagging all of those questions with something more appropriate first, as the tag is very poorly used otherwise.

Comment: There is also the tick marks in graphs (see tags plot, r. lattice, etc) (+1).

Comment: I suggest `timer-tick` for the Microsoft concept.

Comment: I can't imagine why `timer-tick` should be distinct from `timer`.

Comment: The opposite of a tock...

Comment: @RobertHarvey Even with MS there are quite a few different timer ticks. Milliseconds (`GetTickCount`), 100ns (`TimeSpan`), the higher performance counter (`StopWatch`), the interval used for timers and clock increments,...

Comment: For timers, it is typically the amount of time between execution of some bit of logic in between a specified time interval. For charts and checkboxes, that's self explanatory. 

I suppose one reason why 'tick' should be distinct from 'timer' is for the scenario when a timer isn't specified. One particular example of this is 'loop', probably most notably a 'while loop' where the 'tick' interval is implied (by the speed of the processor).

Comment: @CodyGray: Maybe because a timer is a timer, and a tick is an interval.  Weren't you guys the ones who wanted highly-specific, unambiguous tags?

Comment: My favorite superhero! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_tick

Comment: Don't forget the slider tick : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A nervous tick.

Comment: Minecraft ticks are 50 ms, IIRC

Comment: @CodyGray timer is ambiguous since it implies time in terms of seconds (or fractions thereof). Ticks are more specific. It refers to the unit of time measured by the number of timer interrupts. Though to be fair tick is itself ambiguous since some people reimplement their own "tick" in their software event loop.

Comment: It should be tagged with a [tag:tack]

Comment: Should I be ticked off that posted a serious comment above and have no upticks?

Comment: It is a spelling error of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic

Comment: Its obviously a special tag for the Irish SO community to express either: A time when they feel they aren't being as intelligent as usual, or, a time when something isn't "tin".

Comment: Many SO posts are infested with *back ticks*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If everyone agrees (and *If* there's no other option) I'd happily volunteer to at least make a start. Lets face it, the tag is undescriptive, [c](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260624/what-on-earth-is-a-tick#comment43395_260624)[l](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260624/what-on-earth-is-a-tick#comment43385_260624)[e](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260624/what-on-earth-is-a-tick#comment43384_260624)[a](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260624/what-on-earth-is-a-tick#comment43372_260624)[r](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260624/what-on-earth-is-a-tick#comment43038_260624)[l](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260624/what-on-earth-is-a-tick#comment43643_260624)[y](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260624/what-on-earth-is-a-tick#comment43051_260624) it's very ambiguous, and overall just unhelpful.

Comment: You are going to manually remove 150! tags? Is there no moderator option for this?

Comment: @MauriceStam: no there are not. I can't find the corresponding MSE/MSO post right now...  but you can help ! ;)

Comment: @MauriceStam I'm just suggesting that *If* there's no other option I'd be willing to at least make a start at it.

Comment: There is also the `ticks` tag, also with no wiki text, and it occurs more often than the `tick` one. So, you have your work cut out for you.

Comment: If you start, will be happy to lend a hand removing tick and ticks

Comment: @Payeli Much appreciated, it seems we have the "thumbs up" so I'll get started.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose to review the 'Ticks' tag as well. Making it a synonym sounds useless because you can only propose it if you have used the tag (of I think we all did not as we want to remove them).

Answer (score -3):

I believe the most common meaning of the term [tick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tick) by far is [one tick of the CPU clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time).

**CPU-tick is the most correct unit used when measuring a program's speed.** (Seconds are far less relevant, as they depend on the clock speed, other processes running etc.) The execution time of a CPU instruction is measured in ticks. All assembler manuals document such instructions by stating how many ticks an instruction takes. So I'm quite baffled and even embarrassed over all the other interpretations here. Are there really no programmers hanging out on SO Meta?

Still, tick is likely not a useful tag to have. We could rename it to CPU-tick, but I still doubt such a tag would be useful.

Comment: Even in terms of execution time, the definition of a "tick" is not clear. The definition you're aiming at is much more commonly known as a CPU cycle — a "tick" is more often defined in terms of clock time, typically 1/60 or 1/100 of a second.

Comment: @duskwuff Read the Wiki link, it speaks of ticks not cycles. The CPU depends on a clock to work, and one tick of that clock happens to be the same thing as a cycle. The difference is that tick is a measurable unit: you cannot measure cycles, they are an artificial term which you can only calculate in theory.

Comment: Wait, what? CPU cycles are not "artificial" at all. There are tons of ways to measure them — for instance, `rdtsc` on x86 hardware, SysTick on ARM…

Comment: @duskwuff: `rdtsc` doesn't count cycles on *modern* x86 CPUs, though.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's not *exactly* measuring clock cycles, but it's something very closely related to them. Anyways, the point is, "CPU cycles", "CPU ticks", and "ticks of the CPU clock" are synonymous; but "ticks" alone is a generic term that can mean any short period of time.